# Rails validate_uniqueness_of rspec test fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I trying to do testing at validation uniqueness with scope, but it fails

Model

```
 class EcrPortMapping < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :ecr
      validates :ecr_id, presence: true
      validates :ecr_id, uniqueness: {scope: :port_source, message: I18n.t('port_target_in_use')}
      validates :ecr_id, uniqueness: {scope: :port_target, message: I18n.t('port_source_in_use')}
   end
```

test

```
    RSpec.describe EcrPortMapping, type: :model do
  describe 'validations' do

    it 'should validate uniqueness of ecr_id scoped to port_target & port_source' do
      should validate_uniqueness_of(:ecr_id).scoped_to(:port_target)
      should validate_uniqueness_of(:ecr_id).scoped_to(:port_source)
    end
```

error

```
     Failure/Error: should validate_uniqueness_of(:ecr_id).scoped_to(:port_target)
   Expected validation to be scoped to [:port_target], but it was scoped to [:port_source].
```

Answer (score 0):

It fails because it's scoped unique over both `:port_target` *and* `:port_source`. You can pass multiple scopes to `scoped_to`:

```
it 'should validate uniqueness of ecr_id scoped to port_target & port_source' do
  should validate_uniqueness_of(:ecr_id).scoped_to(:port_target, :port_source)
end
```